# UI testing without running a test on a real device

Tags: android, android-testing

Is there some way to test individual `View` components without running the UI test?

For example, can I check cases like this:

- check the change of the `View` state. For example, when the `onClick()` method is called, a change in the state of the `View` (color changes or visibility) is called.
- check that if, for example, in the `RecyclerView.Adapter` I give a list, then it is filled and I can, for example, check some element and check its validity relative to the passed list.
- that when a method is called, an animation starts.

I am not interested in rendering in this case, only the fact of executing the methods I need with the parameters I need.

What tools and approaches are used for this? What about `Robolectric`? I heard not very good reviews about him, can he fulfill my requirements? And are there any alternatives?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

What is the point of testing if a view.setColor() is called if you don't care if the rest is ok? What you should be testing (and therefore using mocks if you want/can) is the logic that triggered said "set color". Who/how did you decide that certain action triggered setColor on X views?

If you say: "but that's in the activity/fragment/onresume, how do I test that?". My answer is: don't put it in the activity/fragment/onresume, put it in a proper viewModel or delegate to a component that has your business logic that you can mock and test.

When an onClick is called, an entity (viewmodel, presenter, etc. should receive the click event, make a decision, and change the "state" of the view(s) in response. NOT the click method deciding to change the view's color on its own.

Why not?

Because that logic may be wrong, may contain a bug, is hard to test as it is, etc. Whereas if it's separate in a "delegate that is tested", it's easier to find/fix/test, etc.